# compare and get the result of two datframes in a single dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to the `python and pandas`. Here, I have a following data-frame

```
df1 = 
A1    B1     A2  B2  A3  B3
null  null   0   2    7   2
103    22     91  0   88  0 
137    22    131  2   126  2
161    2     159  2   157  2

df2 = 

 A4     B4      A5     B5       A6     B6
103    2200     109    0       113    2200
113    2200     126   2200     131    2200
157    200      159   200      161    200
170    200      184    0       195    200
```

I am trying to take A1 from df1 and A4 from df2.

at first, it will be like, null -> 103 Now there is a chance that values in A1 can be null so that I have to take the A3 value if not the A1. or A2

So, It is like the highest value from df1 of A1

and lowest value from df2 of A4

Here I am trying to get the following output

```
start    end    sval        eval
7        103     [2,2]      [2200,0,2200]
103      113     [22,0,0]   [2200,2200,2]
137      157     [22,2,2]   [ 200,200,200]
161      170     [2,2,2]    [ 200,0,200]

So here sval has all the values that are in that row of `B` and eval has all values that have in that row for `B`
```

How can I get this output?

Comment: you wanted to compare the df1 and df1 based on a common key and combine into a  dataframe??

Comment: It is df1 and df2 not just the df1

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the output data frame as shown below.

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index, columns=["start", "end"])
df_out["end"] = pd.DataFrame(df2["A4"])
df_out["start"] = df1[['A1', 'A2', 'A3']].apply(lambda x: np.max(x), axis=1)
df_out["eval"] = df1[['B1', 'B2', 'B3']].apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if not np.isnan(y)], axis=1)
df_out["sval"] = df2[['B4', 'B5', 'B6']].apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if not np.isnan(y)], axis=1)
df_out
```

df1 is

```
    A1  B1  A3  B2
0   NaN NaN 88  162
1   135.0   74.0    149 24
2   97.0    141.0   103 145
3   NaN 138.0   29  162
4   8.0 157.0   6   145
```

df2 is

```
    A4  B3  A5
0   144 107 47
1   52  122 126
2   176 135 132
3   32  25  42
4   16  39  115
```

results in

```
start   end
0   88.0    144
1   135.0   52
2   97.0    176
3   29.0    32
4   8.0 16
```

Comment: Hey I have added the output as well but it is not like that

Comment: you mean the sval and eval columns?

Comment: updated sval and eval columns. I thought you already figured it out how to get those columns.

Comment: here you have not take A2 B2  , A3 B3, A4,B4 ,

Comment: Hey, Just a bit help here while taking the start value we have taken it from the A1 or A3 , but it might be from A2 as well, the thing is the highest value from A1 or A2 or A3 mostly it will be from A1 but if it is null then it will be from A2 or A3 .  And same logic is for A4,A5 and A6  but here we are taking the lowest value

Comment: Hey the thing is that both the dataframes may or may not be in equal rows there will be a diff of 1 row.